# No sound through apps with Bluetooth headset

Tags: sound, bluetooth

I'm having some trouble with a Sony Bluetooth headset.  I have it paired and visible, and the headset is chosen in sound settings.  I can get sound through the headset when I click the speaker test, and also get the sounds the operating system makes when I click through folders.  But when I try to play something through Youtube on Firefox, or play something through VLC, the sound comes out of my laptop speakers.  I can't find a setting that will allow me to get all sound through the headset, not just sounds from the OS.  Does anyone know how I can solve this?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the System Settings and choose the Sound page, you can configure the output devices in that page.  There's also an Applications tab on that page.  I would experiment there first and report back with your findings.